# malloc pointer function passing fread

Tags: c++, c

Can't figure out what's wrong, I don't seem to be getting anything from fread.

### port.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _PORT_
    #define _PORT_
    #include <string>
    #ifndef UNICODE
        typedef char chr;
        typedef string str;
    #else
        typedef wchar_t chr;
        typedef std::wstring str;
        inline void fopen(FILE ** ptrFile, const wchar_t * _Filename,const wchar_t * _Mode)
        {
            _wfopen_s(ptrFile,_Filename,_Mode);
        }
    #endif
#endif
```

### inside main()

```
    File * f = new File(fname,FileOpenMode::Read);
    chr *buffer;
    buffer = (wchar_t*)malloc(f->_length*2);
    for(int i=0;i<f->_length;i++)
    {
      buffer[i] = 0;
    }
    f->Read_Whole_File(buffer);
    f->Close();
    for(int i=0;i<f->_length;i++)
    {
      printf("%S",buffer[i]);
    }
    free(buffer);
```

### inside file class

```
    void Read_Whole_File(chr *&buffer)
    {
        //buffer = (char*)malloc(_length);
        if(buffer == NULL)
        {
            _IsError = true;
            return;
        }
        fseek(_file_pointer, 0, SEEK_SET);
        int a = sizeof(chr);
        fread(&buffer,_length ,sizeof(chr) , _file_pointer);            
    }
```

Comment: Where do you initialise _file_pointer? Seems you are missing 
"this->"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're mixing pointers and references all over the place.

Your function only needs to take a pointer to the buffer:

```
void Read_Whole_File(char *buffer) { ... }
```

And you should pass that pointer as-is to `fread()`, don't take the address of the pointer:

```
size_t amount_read = fread(buffer, _length, sizeof *buffer, _file_pointer);
```

Also remember:

- If you have a pointer `ptr` to some type, you can use `sizeof *ptr` and remove the need to repeat the type name.
- If you know the length of the file already, pass it to the function so you don't need to figure it out twice.
- In C, don't cast the return value of `malloc()`.
- Check for errors when doing memory allocation and I/O, things can fail.

Answer (score 3):

`buffer` is a reference to a `chr *`. Yet you're reading into `&buffer` which is a chr ** (whatever that is). Wrong.

You don't even need to pass a reference to buffer in `Read_Whole_File`, just use a regular pointer.

Answer (score 2):

aside from your original problem...

from your code:

```
typedef char chr;

chr *buffer;
buffer = (wchar_t*)malloc(f->_length*2);
for(int i=0;i<f->_length;i++)
{
  buffer[i] = 0;
}
```

don't you think there is something wrong here ? in case you cannot spot the errors, here is the list:

- `chr` is a `char`, so `buffer` is a `char *`
- you are using `malloc`. are you coding in C or in C++ ? if it is C++, consider using `new`
- the buffer you allocate is explicitly casted to a `wchar_t *` but `buffer` is a `char *`
- in the `malloc` you are allocating a block of size `length*2` when you should be using `length * sizeof(w_char_t)`. don't make any assumption on the size of a type (and even writing `sizeof(char)` is no problem, it renders the intentions explicit)
- the `for` loop goes from 0 to `length`, but since `buffer` is defined as a buffer of `char`, only `length` bytes are initialized, whereas you alocated `length*2` bytes, so half your buffer is still uninitialized.
- `memset()` has been defined to avoid this kind of `for` loop...

please be a little bit careful when coding !

Answer (score 1):

First a couple of nits:

- What's with the malloc and free? What's wrong with new and delete? You are obviously writing C++ here, *so write C++*.
- Overloading fopen, fseek, fread in the case of wchar_t bothers me, immensely. Much better: Use templates, or define your own functions. Don't overload those names that belong to C.

This is not not a nit. The following is almost certainly not doing what you want:

> fread(&buffer,_length ,sizeof(chr) , _file_pointer);

`chr` here is a pointer to a reference, so sizeof is almost certainly going to be either 32 or 64.